# Type 'S3' is missing the following properties from type 'S3Client': destroy, middlewareStack, sendts(2739)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I am getting this error while working on a node backend using typescript and this is the function for file upload to aws S3. Im new to using typescript so can anyone help me on this.

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import multer from "multer";
import multerS3 from "multer-s3";

let S3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3:S3, //error here
        bucket: 'bucket-name',
        metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
        },
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, Date.now().toString())
        }
    })
})


export { upload }
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/multer-s3 Have you installed this?

Comment: @AnonymousUser yes I have but still the same error.

Comment: @sauravscode I'm experiencing the same error, did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 9):

So the problem is that you're creating an s3 client using the version 2 of the sdk instead of the v3 sdk `(@aws-sdk/client-s3)`. The `aws-sdk` provides the version 2 client. `@aws-sdk/client-s3` is part of the V3 javascript SDK.

Make sure to install `npm i @aws-sdk/client-s3`.

You can read about the client s3 sdk [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3)

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import multer from "multer";
import multerS3 from "multer-s3";

const s3Config = new S3Client({
   region: 'us-west-1',
   credentials:{
      accessKeyId:'',
      secretAccessKey:''
  }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3Config,
        bucket: 'bucket-name',
        metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
        },
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, Date.now().toString())
        }
    })
})


export { upload }
```